# execute management command via URL

Tags: django, scrapy

I have the following management command (website.py)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def run_from_argv(self, argv):
        self._argv = argv
        self.execute()

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        from scrapy.cmdline import execute
        execute(self._argv[1:])
```

I'd like to execute this command via URL: /crawl/update-now/
The view is:

```
from django.core import management

def update_index(request):
    management.call_command('website', 'crawl spider')
```

But it's not working:

```
Command' object has no attribute '_argv'
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? What did you end up doing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is that `run_from_argv` is internal Django method and called by django.core.management.ManagementUtility. And you should not implement it by yourself, self._argv is not set anywhere. Arguments are already available in handle().

And your approach has some disadvantages.

First of all, due to synchronous nature of Django, if your URL is "heavy" it can take a lot of time to get it and parse. Instead of it, I'm strongly recommend you to take a look at [Celery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery). It is more "right" way to execute tasks from views and has no problems with performance.